# Add Class On Page Reload In Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm kind of new w/ react and nextjs. How can insert a script in a component to add class in  when the page reload? It seems like the code below don't work because the page is not yet rendered when I add the class for the body tag.

```
const ModeToggler = (props: Props) => {
  // ** Props
  const { settings, saveSettings } = props

  const handleModeChange = (mode: PaletteMode) => {
    saveSettings({ ...settings, mode })
  }

  const handleModeToggle = () => {
    if (settings.mode === 'light') {
      handleModeChange('dark');
      document.body.classList.add('mode-dark');
    } else {
      handleModeChange('light');
      document.body.classList.remove('mode-dark');
    }
  }

  // This will not work because the page is not rendered yet right?
  if (settings.mode === 'light') {
    document.body.classList.add('mode-dark');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('mode-dark');
  }

  return (
    <IconButton color='inherit' aria-haspopup='true' onClick={handleModeToggle}>
      {settings.mode === 'dark' ? <WeatherSunny /> : <WeatherNight />}
    </IconButton>
  )
}

export default ModeToggler
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, since the class is dependent on the prop `settings`
I would suggest you use a useEffect with a dependency of that prop. So not only will it retrieve the value and apply the style on render, but also re-render/apply style each time the prop changes.

```
          const ModeToggler = (props: Props) => {
          // ** Props
          const { settings, saveSettings } = props
        
          const handleModeChange = (mode: PaletteMode) => {
            saveSettings({ ...settings, mode })
          }
        
          const handleModeToggle = () => {
            if (settings.mode === 'light') {
              handleModeChange('dark');
              document.body.classList.add('mode-dark');
            } else {
              handleModeChange('light');
              document.body.classList.remove('mode-dark');
            }
          }
        
    
        useEffect(() => {
         if (settings.mode === 'light') {
          document.body.classList.add('mode-dark');
         } else {
           document.body.classList.remove('mode-dark');
         }
        }, [settings.mode])

          return (
            <IconButton color='inherit' aria-haspopup='true' onClick={handleModeToggle}>
              {settings.mode === 'dark' ? <WeatherSunny /> : <WeatherNight />}
            </IconButton>
          )
        }
        
        export default ModeToggler
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can detect if your page is reload or not using `window.performance`
> for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByType

```
useEffect(()=>{
let entries = window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
if(entries[0]=="reload"){
 // add class to an element;

}
},[])
```